# What is the difference between google's ImmutableList and Collections.unmodifiableList ()?

Tags: java, collections, comparison, guava

From ImmutableList javadocs:

> Unlike
>   Collections.unmodifiableList(java.util.List),
>   which is a view of a separate
>   collection that can still change, an
>   instance of ImmutableList contains its
>   own private data and will never
>   change. ImmutableList is convenient
>   for public static final lists
>   ("constant lists") and also lets you
>   easily make a "defensive copy" of a
>   list provided to your class by a
>   caller.

Does it mean that:

1. if I have ImmutableList of Dimension objects (for example) then I can't change any Dimension object in it?
2. and if I have Collections.unmodifiableList (list) of Dimension objects then I can't only add or delete any object but I can change them (for example call setDimension(width, height) method)?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [What's the difference between Collections.unmodifiableSet() and ImmutableSet of Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5611324/977087)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, the immutability is only applied to the amount and references of the objects in the `Collection`, and does not address the mutability of objects you put in the `Collection`.

What Immutable list gains over the standard JDK `Collections.unmodifiableList` is that by using `ImmutableList` you are guaranteed that the objects referenced, their order and the size of the list cannot change from any source. With `Collections.unmodifiableList` if something else has a reference to the underlying list, that code can modify the list even though you have a reference to an unmodifiable list.

If, however, you want true immutability, you have to fill the list with immutable objects.

Comment: @Vuntic, if the class is truly immutable, its fields are declared final, and reflection can't change that.

Comment: @Yishai, reflection *can* modify final fields. Try it.

Comment: @Vuntic, with setAccessible? That depends on the security manager ;).

Comment: @Yishai... yes, it does depend on the security manager. The normal security manager allows this. The question makes no reference to security managers. And that (setAccessible) is not even how you modify final fields.

Comment: @Vuntic, I get an exception when I try to modify a final field without setting setAccessable. What are you thinking of? BTW, the question made no reference to reflection either ;)

Comment: @Yishai I know I'm 7 years late to this conversation... but for the public record you modify final fields by first using reflection to remove the final modifier.  It only works on Objects though, not on primitives.

Answer (score 20):

Using `Collections.unmodifiableList` creates a wrapper around your List. if the underlying list changes, so does your unmodifiableList's view.

As the documentation says, Google's code creates a copy. It's a more expensive computation and consumes more memory, but if someone alters the original list, it cant affect the ImmutableList.

Neither of these will prevent you from changing an object in a list, or it's fields, or fields of fields, etc.

Comment: "As the documentation says, Google's code creates a copy." It *might* create a copy. If the original is also an immutable data structure, it might actually be able to reuse it. So if you use `ImmutableList` extensively, you'll hit this case very often and will end up not having to copy very much.

Answer (score 7):

`ImmutableList` is similar to `Collections.unmodifiableList( new ArrayList( list ) )` . Note that the newly created `ArrayList` is **not** assigned to a field or variable.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, the contained individual objects can still be modified.  A collection is really only storing *references* to the contained objects, not a full copy of every object.
2. You can modify the list by modifying the parent Collection you called Collections.unmodifiableList(list) on.  But yes, you CAN use setDimension to change a stored list element.