# How to efficiently store objects in a LoadingCache, that may have more than one key

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a data structure where I have objects, and they have targets. and they have a many to many relationship.
For eg: object1 has targets: t1, t2, t3 and
object2 has targets: t2, t3.

I want to write a Guava LoadingCache in order to store each of these objects by target. Now, the problem with this is: Objects 1 and 2 both will be stored under t2, and t3. And this is wastage.

So, one solution I thought of was to have another map of ids. And in the target cache, I'll store the object by their id.

Now, the question is: Since in a LoadingCache we dont have methods exposed that take care of clearing the cache(or a way to listen to when the cache gets cleared.), I have no way of keeping the id map upto date, when the cache actually gets updated.

Is there a good way of keeping these two maps in sync?

Comment: I think I have a rough idea of what you want to achieve, however, it would be better to have simplified code as example. My specific question at the moment is: What needs to be kept in sync? Is just value changing or the target association? Maybe a description of the original problem scenario would be great also to avoid the XY-Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I question your premises, specifically that "this is wastage."  You're storing multiple *references* to objects, not multiple copies of the objects themselves, and references are cheap.  Having another map of ids is likely to be *strictly more expensive* than your original approach in the first place.

Comment: Louis, I think the assumption is not correct, since the loading cache will construct a new instance for each target. The loader could, however, query the cache in turn whether there is a mapping on an "alias" target....

Comment: @cruftex, it is not a given that the cache must construct a new instance for each target, and only the OP can tell us which is the case.   To me, it sounds like the cache is probably not constructing a new instance for each target.

Comment: So the cache will look like this <String, ImmutableList<DataObject>>, and immutablelist makes a new copy, as far as I know. So it actually does make copies of the objects. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What?  ImmutableList doesn't copy objects added to it.  There's no way in Java to universally copy objects.

Comment: AFAIK ImmutableList does'nt store by reference, because if I have the reference to the object, and if I change it. Then the list is not immutable anymore. And I did run a small program to check if changes made to the object using its reference, is reflected in the object stored in the list or not. And it does not. I am new to this, so it'd be great if you can explain this in a bit more detail.

Comment: @SThomas, that's simply not the case.  ImmutableList does store by reference, and you can change its elements if they're of a mutable type.  It seems likely that you either misunderstand something or that your program is incorrect.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2185789/869736 for some explanation.